# The type org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

```
package com.gk.rating.service.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.gk.rating.service.entity.Rating;

@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends MongoRepository<Rating, String> {

    // custom finder methods
    List<Rating> findByUserId(String userId);

    List<Rating> findByHotelId(String hotelId);
}
```

This particular error is showing in console.The type org.springframework.data.domain.Sort cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: This is a dependency issue. Please put your pom or gradle in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the pom.xml. Try with version left out for starters.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After adding this dependency, I'm getting this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.getRepositoryConfigurationExtension(MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:62)

Comment: Google “maven InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException”. You will see this page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao/2.0.3 on the hits. You will have to add this dependancy until they all resolve.